# Selecting all links under only one div

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to select all of the links contained under this one div in this kind of structure:

```
<div id = "logged_hits">
   <div class="toHigh nl">
     <a href="(link i want to click)">/a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to click all the links under the "logged_hits" id since the structure of the html contains many links under this one div. I am selecting the div by its XPath here:

```
 List<IWebElement> allLinks = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("/html/body/div[6]")).ToList();
```

Then looping through each element in the list

```
        foreach (var value in allLinks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value.GetAttribute("href").ToString());
        }
```

I get no values since I dont think it can find the a tags. Any help would be greatly appriciated

Comment: Please clarify, many div with `logged_hits` id or one `logged_hits` and many links under it?

Comment: @Sers One div with the ID = logged_hits with many links under it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all link in `logged_hits` div you can use `#logged_hits a` css selector or `//div[@id='logged_hits']//a` xpath.

```
List<IWebElement> allLinks = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#logged_hits a"));
foreach (IWebElement link in allLinks) {
    Console.WriteLine(link.GetAttribute("href").ToString());
}
```